# node js callback as var

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Am trying to create a method that i can call from all parts of my express app, i simply pass a value to this method and it searches through mongodb using moongose to see if user exists, then it returns a Boolean as result.

```
function findUserExists(name){

 User.findOne({ "name": name }, function(err, user) {

 if (user){ 
    console.log("user exits");
    return true;
 }
 else{ 
        console.log("user not exits");
    return false; }
});
```

Now when i call it in another method like this, it doesn't return the Boolean value in time.

```
if (findUserExists("username")){

// redirect to dashboard
console.log("user exits");
    res.redirect('/dashboard');
}
else {
 // redirect to sign up page
console.log("user must sign up");
    res.redirect('/signup');
}
```

So in this case the other functions run before getting the Boolean value from the findUserExists(), my question is how can i make this function return a value before other functions run, in a way that i can call it in an IF condition or even a var like this

```
var exists = findUserExists(name);
```

Comment: Can you nest "other function" in a if statement? or call them from your if (findUserExists("username")){

//the function to call
}

Comment: @Sulot it's only a routing statement to know if user exists then redirect to dashboard page, if not redirect to sign up page, i updated my question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to force synchronous code on asynchronous function. 
Short answer is: **you shouldn't do this**

Convert your function to callback

```
function findUserExists(name, callback) {
    User.findOne({ "name": name }, function (err, user) {
        callback(user);
    });
}
```

and then use as this:

```
findUserExists("username", function (exists) {
    if (exists) {
        console.log("user exits");
        res.redirect('/dashboard');
    } else {
        console.log("user must sign up");
        res.redirect('/signup');
    }
});
```

You can use **promises** to code look more synchronous if you use node 4 and above.

Answer (score 2):

In your logic there is a problem, you are *not handling errors* that might occur in the query itself like DB server down. **Avoid using callbacks** as much as possible and switch to promises, async await, etc..

***Using Promises:***

If no call back is passed to Mongoose, then it will return a Promise. If query is **successfull** it will **resolve** with document. In this case if user **does not exists**, then it will be resolved with a **null** ([link](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOne)), if user exists then it will be resolved with that document. In case if **query fails**, for example DB server unavailable etc, then the promise will be **rejected** with an err object.

**DB call**

```
  function findUserExists(name){
    return User.findOne({ "name": name })
    .then(function(doc){//This function will be executed if DB query was successful.
      //You can write additional logic if any to handle the returned doc here
      return doc;
    }, function(err){// This function will be executed if something goes wrong with db server or query.
      //You can write logic for error handling in DB connection like logging DB failure.
      return err;
    })
  }
```

**Validation:**

```
findUserExists(name)
.then(function(user){//Resolved callback: This function is executed if previous promise was resolved
  if(!user){ //If user does not exist null will be returned
    console.log('User must sign up');
    return res.redirect('/signup');
  }
  console.log('User Exists');
  return res.redirect('/dashboard');
},function(err){ //This function is executed if previous promise is rejected
  console.log('Some error occurred in DB query');
})
```

Comment: Nice deeply explanation. You cover promises and error handling which are important in real application. Ceddy's question didn't mentioned error handling - sometimes it's better to extract only problem from your application and not trying to cover all possible topics.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your `findUserExists` function calls an asynchronous but you're trying to use it synchronously.

In order to achieve what you're looking to do, you need to provide your function with a callback function or return a promise. The easiest way, since you're already using callbacks in mongoose would be like this:

```
    function findUserExists(name , callback ){
     User.findOne({ "name": name }, function(err, user) {
      if( err ) callback( err );
      else if (user){
        console.log("user exits");
        callback( null, true );
      }
      else{
        console.log("user does not exist");
        callback( null, false );
      }
    });

    findUserExists( "username", function( err, user ){
      if( err ) console.log( err );
      else if( user ){
        console.log("user exits");
        res.redirect('/dashboard');
        // redirect to dashboard
      }
      else {
       // redirect to sign up page
        console.log("user must sign up");
        res.redirect('/signup');
      }
    }
```